# Problema al migrar pagina wordpress a servidor - HTACCESS ERROR

Tags: wordpress

No entiendo que sucede, mi página funciona bien en localhost, esta todo actualizado.
La he migrado a mi servidor, conectado a la base de datos y todo, y se vee como si el css no existiera.

Además me aparecen estos errores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna idea de que puede estar ocurriendo ??

Luego de ir a los foros de Wordpress, ellos me hicieron hablar con mi hosting. Llegando a resolver lo de los mime/types, pero dejando estos errores.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Luego de resolver los problemas de MIME type con el hosting, solo quedaban los errores de la segunda imagen. 
Yo estaba seguro que tenia que ver con el .htaccess,
Asi que fui probando diferentes combinaciones, hasta que se solucionó.
Por si alguno le sirve dejaré la página.

https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/

Comment: Pues supuestamente, que hay un `<` de más en tu código en las líneas que te indica ahí. Cuidado si al cambiar un `<script>` pusiste un `<` de más y te da error luego ahí :)

Comment: Quizás el error sea del htaccess la verdad

Comment: A mi me ocurrió lo mismo con el ```<``` y la cosa era que al traer un dato de mi base de datos el campo no existía y también se me olvido poner una ```,```, verifica todo du backend

Comment: Pero el tema es donde verificarlo ?¿ por que no encuentro donde haya un error

Comment: Tampoco puedo replicar los errores en el localhost, entonces no encuentro que hacer

Comment: Como estas llamando tus archivos, cual es la ruta o el código php que usas para agregarlos a la cola de estilos de WordPress?

Comment: Yo no los genero, los genera Wordpress, asi que no tengo idea de por que en localhost se vee perfecto, pero no en el hosting

Comment: Que tienes en la tabla wp_option de phpmyadmin revisa el site url y admin url que sea la tuya y trata de refrescas los enlaces permanentes

Comment: SI ERA EL JODIDO HTACCESS !!!, probé muchas configuraciones de este archivo, y finalmente se han resolvido los problemas !!!!